# Including caret in another package gives error during devtools::check() - "there is no package called 'lattice'"

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to include caret in a package that I am developing. When I run devtools::check(), I get an error "there is no package called 'lattice'". If I remove caret from the "Imports" section of the DESCRIPTION file, the error goes away. I am not sure what is causing this issue. Lattice is installed on my machine.

I don't know how to provide a reproducible example since the package is in development so I have included a version of the package [here](https://github.com/josephsdavid/tswgewrapped/blob/1.8.10.1/build/tswgewrapped_1.8.10.1.tar.gz). If it helps, my DESCRIPTION file (without caret) looks like this

```
Package: tswgewrapped
Title: Helpful wrappers for 'tswge', 'vars' and 'nnfor' time series packages
Version: 1.8.10
Authors@R: c(
    person("David", "Josephs", email = "josephsd@smu.edu", role = c("aut", "cre")),
    person("Nikhil", "Gupta", email = "guptan@smu.edu", role = c("aut")))
Description: This package provides several helpful wrappers for the already useful 'tswge', 'vars' and 'nnfor' package. In the future, this package intends to move away from the tswge backend, to be faster, with more readable source code.
License: AGPL-3
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Imports: 
    assertr,
    doParallel,
    dplyr,
    ggfortify,
    GGally,
    ggplot2,
    magrittr,
    nnfor,
    rlang,
    pander,
    parallel,
    patchwork,
    purrr,
    R6,
    RColorBrewer,
    Rfast,
    tibble,
    tictoc,
    tswge,
    vars,
    forecast
RoxygenNote: 7.1.0
Suggests: 
    testthat (>= 2.1.0),
    tseries,
    knitr,
    rmarkdown
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

Here is my sessionInfo

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tswgewrapped_1.8.10 caret_6.0-84        ggplot2_3.3.0       lattice_0.20-41    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] colorspace_1.4-1    class_7.3-15        rprojroot_1.3-2     fs_1.3.1            rstudioapi_0.10     roxygen2_7.1.0     
  [7] remotes_2.1.0       smooth_2.5.5        lubridate_1.7.4     prodlim_2018.04.18  xml2_1.2.0          splines_3.5.1      
 [13] codetools_0.2-16    doParallel_1.0.14   knitr_1.23          pkgload_1.0.2       greybox_0.5.8       nloptr_1.2.1       
 [19] compiler_3.5.1      tictoc_1.0          backports_1.1.4     assertthat_0.2.1    RcppZiggurat_0.1.5  Matrix_1.2-17      
 [25] strucchange_1.5-2   cli_1.1.0           prettyunits_1.0.2   tools_3.5.1         gtable_0.3.0        glue_1.3.1         
 [31] reshape2_1.4.3      dplyr_0.8.5         Rcpp_1.0.1          fracdiff_1.4-2      xopen_1.0.0         lamW_1.3.0         
 [37] urca_1.3-0          tswge_1.0.0         nlme_3.1-137        iterators_1.0.10    vars_1.5-3          lmtest_0.9-37      
 [43] timeDate_3043.102   gower_0.2.1         xfun_0.8            stringr_1.4.0       ps_1.3.0            testthat_2.1.1     
 [49] devtools_2.1.0      statmod_1.4.33      MASS_7.3-51.4       zoo_1.8-6           scales_1.0.0        ipred_0.9-9        
 [55] parallel_3.5.1      sandwich_2.5-1      RColorBrewer_1.1-2  yaml_2.2.0          quantmod_0.4-15     curl_3.3           
 [61] memoise_1.1.0       gridExtra_2.3       pander_0.6.3        rcmdcheck_1.3.3     rpart_4.1-15        reshape_0.8.8      
 [67] stringi_1.4.3       tseries_0.10-47     desc_1.2.0          foreach_1.4.4       TTR_0.23-4          pkgbuild_1.0.3     
 [73] lava_1.6.5          rlang_0.4.2         pkgconfig_2.0.2     purrr_0.3.3         nnfor_0.9.6         recipes_0.1.6      
 [79] patchwork_1.0.0     Rfast_1.9.9         processx_3.4.1      tidyselect_0.2.5    GGally_1.5.0        plyr_1.8.4         
 [85] magrittr_1.5        R6_2.4.0            generics_0.0.2      pillar_1.4.2        withr_2.1.2         xts_0.11-2         
 [91] survival_2.44-1.1   nnet_7.3-12         ggfortify_0.4.8     tibble_2.1.3        crayon_1.3.4        usethis_1.5.1      
 [97] grid_3.5.1          data.table_1.12.2   callr_3.3.1         ModelMetrics_1.2.2  forecast_8.9        digest_0.6.20      
[103] MAPA_2.0.4          assertr_2.7         tidyr_0.8.3         numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 tsutils_0.9.2       stats4_3.5.1       
[109] RcppParallel_4.4.3  munsell_0.5.0       sessioninfo_1.1.1   quadprog_1.5-7
```

Comment: Did you try to add lattice as Import to your package along with caret?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the solution to my issue.

**Solution 1**

I had installed R on my new compute more than a year ago and hence was using version 3.5.1. For some reason (you can see my my SessionInfo), caret and lattice were showing up under  `other attached packages` and not under `loaded via a namespace (and not attached)`.

I also noticed that if I place caret in the my package namespace, then the installation part of the `devtools::check()` went though without any issue, but the process complained about lattice during the unit tests section.

So the temporary solution that I found was to install `lattice` and the `forecast` packages in the unit test setup section (testthat.R). This does not seem like a clean solution but it worked. You can see that [here - version 1.8.10.8 of the package](https://github.com/josephsdavid/tswgewrapped/blob/master/build/tswgewrapped_1.8.10.8.tar.gz).

```
if(!require("lattice")){
  # https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/411#issuecomment-209973908
  install.packages("lattice", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org", dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports", "Suggests"))
}

if(!require("forecast")){
  # https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/411#issuecomment-209973908
  install.packages("forecast", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org", dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports", "Suggests"))
}
```

**Solution 2**

Yesterday, I upgraded to the latest version of R (3.6.3) and installed all the packages again. Now you can see from my SessionInfo that `caret` and `lattice` correctly show up under the `loaded via a namespace (and not attached)` section.

And now, everything works fine with `devtools::check()` even if I remove the `lattice` and `forecast` package installation from the unit test setup section. So I believe there was some issue with the older version of R and how it was interacting with my setup.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tswgewrapped_1.8.10.9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] colorspace_1.4-1     ellipsis_0.3.0       class_7.3-15         rprojroot_1.3-2      fs_1.4.1             rstudioapi_0.11     
  [7] roxygen2_7.1.0       remotes_2.1.1        smooth_2.5.6         prodlim_2019.11.13   fansi_0.4.1          lubridate_1.7.8     
 [13] xml2_1.3.1           codetools_0.2-16     splines_3.6.3        doParallel_1.0.15    knitr_1.28           pkgload_1.0.2       
 [19] greybox_0.5.9        nloptr_1.2.2.1       pROC_1.16.2          caret_6.0-86         compiler_3.6.3       tictoc_1.0          
 [25] backports_1.1.6      assertthat_0.2.1     RcppZiggurat_0.1.5   Matrix_1.2-18        strucchange_1.5-2    cli_2.0.2           
 [31] prettyunits_1.1.1    tools_3.6.3          gtable_0.3.0         glue_1.4.0           reshape2_1.4.4       dplyr_0.8.5         
 [37] Rcpp_1.0.4.6         xopen_1.0.0          fracdiff_1.5-1       vctrs_0.2.4          lamW_1.3.0           urca_1.3-0          
 [43] tswge_1.0.0          nlme_3.1-144         iterators_1.0.12     vars_1.5-3           lmtest_0.9-37        timeDate_3043.102   
 [49] gower_0.2.1          xfun_0.13            stringr_1.4.0        ps_1.3.2             testthat_2.3.2       lifecycle_0.2.0     
 [55] devtools_2.3.0       statmod_1.4.34       MASS_7.3-51.5        zoo_1.8-7            scales_1.1.0         ipred_0.9-9         
 [61] parallel_3.6.3       sandwich_2.5-1       RColorBrewer_1.1-2   quantmod_0.4.17      curl_4.3             memoise_1.1.0       
 [67] gridExtra_2.3        ggplot2_3.3.0        pander_0.6.3         rcmdcheck_1.3.3      rpart_4.1-15         reshape_0.8.8       
 [73] stringi_1.4.6        tseries_0.10-47      desc_1.2.0           foreach_1.5.0        TTR_0.23-6           pkgbuild_1.0.6      
 [79] lava_1.6.7           rlang_0.4.5          pkgconfig_2.0.3      pracma_2.2.9         lattice_0.20-38      purrr_0.3.4         
 [85] nnfor_0.9.6          recipes_0.1.10       patchwork_1.0.0      Rfast_1.9.9          processx_3.4.2       tidyselect_1.0.0    
 [91] GGally_1.5.0         plyr_1.8.6           magrittr_1.5         R6_2.4.1             generics_0.0.2       pillar_1.4.3        
 [97] withr_2.1.2          xts_0.12-0           survival_3.1-8       nnet_7.3-12          ggfortify_0.4.9      tibble_3.0.0        
[103] crayon_1.3.4         usethis_1.6.0        grid_3.6.3           data.table_1.12.8    callr_3.4.3          ModelMetrics_1.2.2.2
[109] forecast_8.12        digest_0.6.25        MAPA_2.0.4           assertr_2.7          tidyr_1.0.2          tsutils_0.9.2       
[115] RcppParallel_5.0.0   stats4_3.6.3         munsell_0.5.0        sessioninfo_1.1.1    quadprog_1.5-8
```

I hope this will be helpful for future readers. **Lesson learned is to not be too out of sync with the latest version of the tool and packages**.